# Issue accessing to DataSet in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm actually trying to calculate the mean time between one question and its response on twitter using apache-spark, the twitter API and cassandra.

But when I'm trying to access the DataSet returned by the CassandraConnector I only get NullPointerException.

```
  def getTweets(inReplyToStatusId : Long, timestamp : DateTime ): String = {

  if(inReplyToStatusId > 0){
    CassandraConnector(TwitterStreamingApp.conf).withSessionDo { session =>
      val reply_id = session.execute("SELECT created_at FROM twitter_streaming.tweets WHERE tweet_id ="+ inReplyToStatusId+"ALLOW FILTERING")
      val reply_time_it = reply_id.all().get(0).getString("created_at")
      print(reply_time_it)
    }
  }
}
```

any idea on how to do this in scala ? It seems pretty easy but I am struggling a lot on this !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most suspicious line is

```
val reply_time_it = reply_id.all().get(0).getString("created_at")
```

Since any non-key field could be absent in the cassandra record, it's very likely to be `null` sometimes.  You can wrap it in option like

```
val reply_time_it = Option( reply_id.all().get(0).getString("created_at"))
```

Then you can use methods like `getOrElse` to get value with default, `forEach` to execute side-effecting method if value is present, and `map` to make new values based on that.

Also you should probably:

- create one session for each partition using `mapPartions` or `mapPartitionsWithIndex`
- create `PreparedStatement` for each query \ partition [for performance reasons](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I managed to use the option() and the application is now running fine :)